# An application of Snake Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, quiver

I am stuck at undderstanding a claim made in Derksen's book *An Introduction to Quiver Representations*.
This is Lemma 2.4.3. But the part I am stuck at is purely homological algebra it seems.

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and $V$ and $W$ are two modules.

Suppose we have length injective and projective resolutions as follows (this happens for all modules in our context, but that doesn't matter here):

$0 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to V \to 0$ and

$0 \to W \to I^{0} \to I^{1} \to 0$.

Using the usual right, left exactness of the various functors we get the following diagram (take $Q$ as $A$)

[image]

**Now the claim that I dont understand is**:

'Using the snake Lemma to the above diagram it follows that the cokernel of $Hom_{A}(P_0, W) \to Hom_{A}(P_1, W)$ is isomorphic to $Hom_{A}(V, I^{0}) \to Hom_{A}(V, I^{1})$.

I know that this will be true since both are equal to $Ext^{1}(V, W)$ from the homological algebra definition of $Ext$ in terms of derived functors.

But I want to do it directly in this situation by applying the Snake Lemma as suggested by the author but I don't see how to.

Please help.

Comment: Apply the Snake Lemma to the middle and right hand columns.